# Microsoft Bot Framework - How to know user Time and IP to trace location

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework to create a chatbot.
How to know user's Timezone and his IP to trace location.
This will help me give better service to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could get this is from the channel client, so it is dependent on channel.

There is a ChannelData object that shows you what you can get, but I'm not sure if these are on there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-channeldata

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ChannelData

If you have implemented your own client, for example for webchat, then you could gather this information from there and pass it down or send it to your analytics solution.